# MediaWiki: Convert seconds to HH:MM:SS

Tags: mediawiki

How do I convert seconds to HH.MM:SS via MediaWiki (plus Semantic Media Wiki)?
I tried and tried and just can't find a way.

The duration in seconds comes via filling out a template.
As I can't install more extensions to the Wiki the only ways are via SMW and parser functions.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the time parser function:

```
{{#time: H.i.s | @123 }}
```

It't not strickly treating it as a time duration, but rather a time from the unix epoch, but if you don't go over 24 hours it doesn't really matter.

If you need to go higher, then you can build up a custom expression using the `trunc` operator, for example to get the number of hours:

```
{{#expr: trunc (123/60/60) }}
```

Comment: Wow, that works like a charm. Thank you very much, Sam!